# Spring spring.profiles.include: doesn't read profile-related properties

Tags: spring-boot

There are several ways present to define **"active profiles"** for a Spring Boot application.
The default one is to pass it through a command line, like this:

`java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,local -jar myapp.jar`

it works just fine (as expected): All *three* sets of profile-related properties will be loaded in proper order:

1. `application.yaml`
2. `application-dev.yaml` will override the previous one
3. `application-local.yaml` will override the previous one as well (these properties will have the most priority)

Based on the idea, that my **"local"** profile should always **"use and overrides"** properties from the **"dev"**, let's "hardcode" such behavior.

Let's use the `'spring.profiles.include'` feature for this. So, the following lines are added to the `'application-local.yaml'`:

```
spring.profiles:
    include:
        - dev
```

I expect, now I can pass the **"local"** profile only in the command line, and the **"dev"** profile will be applied automatically (with his properties, of course):

`java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar myapp.jar`

But **ooop!***: properties from the `'application-dev.yaml'` are ignored.

**Why? Is it a bug? Is it a feature that forces me to list all profiles in a command line directly?**

I'm sure that the behavior around profiles activation should be the same without any difference in how the active-profiles list was passed to Spring Boot framework.

*The application:*

```
@SpringBootApplication @EnableConfigurationProperties( MyProps::class )
class SpringApp4

@ConfigurationProperties("my.db") @ConstructorBinding
data class MyProps(val name: String, val url:  String, val user: String)

@Component
class MyRunner(val myProps: MyProps, val env: Environment) : CommandLineRunner {
    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        println("myProps         = $myProps")
        println("activeProfiles  = ${env.activeProfiles.joinToString()}")
        exitProcess(0)
    }
}

fun main() { runApplication<SpringApp4>() }
```

*application.yaml:*

```
my.db:
    name: "default-name"
    url:  "default-url"
    user: "default-user"
```

*application-dev.yaml:*

```
my.db:
    url:  "dev-url"
    user: "dev-user"
```

*application-local.yaml:*

```
spring.profiles.include:
    - dev
my.db:
    user: "local-user"
```

*Run1:* `java -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,local -jar myapp.jar`
Correct output:

```
myProps         = MyProps(name=default-name, url=dev-url, user=local-user)
activeProfiles  = dev, local
```

it's correct because the `url=dev-url`

*Run2:* `java -Dspring.profiles.active=local -jar myapp.jar`
Incorrect output:

```
myProps         = MyProps(name=default-name, url=default-url, user=local-user)
activeProfiles  = local
```

It's *not* correct because the `url=default-url` and the `activeProfiles` doesn't contain the "dev" at all.

Help me please to figure out how to use the `spring.profiles.include` feature in yaml to build a kind of top *level profiles* that will activate other automatically.

Comment: @NakulGoyal, 
tested by you recommendation. the "local" profile was renamed to "bar" (and the profile-file as well)

the output:
```
myProps         = MyProps(name=default-name, url=default-url, user=bar-user)
activeProfiles  = bar
```

so - the same issue in place :-(

Answer (score 0):

In **Run2** You are giving profile as **local**
i.e

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=local
```

So spring will first load **application.yml** and then **application-local.yml**

I can see the output is expected.

Since some properties like name and url are not present in application-local.yml, so the values of these fields will be same as present in application.yml

*FYI : application.yml is always called irrespective of profile, and then it gets overridden by the profile mentioned in -Dspring.profiles.active property*

Comment: Yes, it how it's going now. 
But, at the same tine,  have the following line in my *application-local.yml*:
`spring.profiles.include:
    - dev`

so, SpringBoot should _add_ the *dev* profile into the account and load the *application-dev.yaml*, Don't you think so, @Nakul ?

Answer (score 0):

`spring.profiles.include` deprecated in Spring Boot 2.4 and no longer works: https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4

It caused recursive resource loading; that broke Kubernates ConfigMap so they removed recursion.

Use `spring.profiles.active` or `spring.profiles.group`.